# Trying to build a class with a string array

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi im trying to build a very basic quiz app with asp.net. I have a quiz class with a string array and a string answer. I then trying to make a new quiz object and add four question to array. Add them to session and display on another page in a label.

**Button Click**

```
    protected void Unnamed8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Quiz one = new Quiz();
        one.answer = "First";
        one.questions[0] = "First";
        one.questions[1] = "Second";
        one.questions[2] = "Third";
        one.questions[3] = "Fourth";

        Session["Thequiz"] = one;
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
    }
```

**Quiz Class**

```
    public class Quiz
    {
        public string[] questions; 
        public string answer { get; set; }

        public Quiz()
        {
            questions = new string[] {"First","Second","Third","Fourth"};
        }
    }
```

**Display.aspx trying to remove first element of array and add it to the label**

```
   namespace Quiz
   {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
           Quiz was;
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

             was = (Quiz)Session["Thequiz"];
              was.answer = (string)display.Text;
           }
        }
   }
```

The label is blank just wondering why.

Comment: just wondering where I have gone wrong

Comment: First, what error did you see (InvalidCast error)?

Comment: no error just the label was blank

Comment: Probably you want `display.Text = was.answer;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reverse the label and assignment value.

```
 display.Text = was.answer;
```

Comment: @FrancisGall You should mark this as the answer if it answers the question.  Increases your rep a little, and shows appreciation to this poster for his/her time.